# Conditional grouping query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I need to get all the `Room_IDs` where the `Status` is different between the last and any prior `Inspection_Date`.

This is a simplified table I am using as an example:

```
 **Room_Id   Status    Inspection_Date**
    1        vacant      5/15/2015
    2        occupied    5/21/2015
    2        vacant      1/19/2016
    1        occupied   12/16/2015
    4        vacant      3/25/2016
    3        vacant      8/27/2015
    1        vacant      4/17/2016
    3        vacant     12/12/2015
    3        occupied    3/22/2016
    4        vacant       2/2/2015
    4        vacant      3/24/2015
```

My result should look like this:

```
 **Room_Id  Status  Inspection_Date**
    1       vacant      5/15/2015
    1      occupied    12/16/2015
    1       vacant      4/17/2016
    2      occupied     5/21/2015
    2       vacant      1/19/2016
    3       vacant      8/27/2015
    3       vacant     12/12/2015
    3      occupied     3/22/2016
```

I tried this but I am honestly not sure if the logic is correct.

```
Select *
FROM TableX x1
WHERE EXISTS 
( SELECT 1 
FROM TableX X2
WHERE X2.Room_Id = X1.Room_Id
GROUP BY X2.Room_Id
HAVING  max (Status) <> min (Status))
```

Comment: Why would you show 8/27/2015 and 12/12/2015 for Room_Id = 3 when the status didn't change from 8/27 to 12/12?  Shouldn't it only be the 12/12 and 3/22 dates that would show?  Otherwise you could have a room be vacant for example for 10 years and then become occupied and you'd still pull all 10 years of data where it was vacant.  You really want that?

Comment: @Dresden yes I do, we do not keep the rooms for that long and actually all I need is the IDs so in this case:
    1 - 2 - 3

Comment: Ok so you would only need to check and see when the distinct status count for a room id is more than 1.  Then you would pull all the information for that room id.  Even if you did inspections multiple times a day if the status changes it still technically happens after the earlier inspection.  You wouldn't even have to worry about dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the first (latest inspection_date) row for each room_id, using `row_number` function and join it to the remaining rows (for that room) and check to see if the status is different on any of those rows. If different, select the room_id and subsequently all the rows in the table for that room_id.

```
select * from tablename
where room_id in (
select t1.room_id 
from (select t.*, row_number() over(partition by room_id order by inspection_date desc) rn 
      from tablename t) t1
join tablename t2 on t1.room_id = t2.room_id and t1.rn = 1
where t1.status <> t2.status
)
```

[Sample Demo](http://rextester.com/ZBFK91528)

Comment: Mine works as well but yours is more precise, Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

But last and any prior is the same as two or more values

```
select t1.room_id 
from ( select t.*
            , row_number() over(partition by room_id, status order by inspection_date desc) rn
            , count(*)  over(partition by room_id, status order by inspection_date desc) cnt
     ) tt 
 where tt.rn = 1 
   and tt.cnt > 1
```